# Get LHS in drools 6.5 to show in taskform

Tags: drools, jbpm

We have a situation where if rule fails, we need to show what condition is failed. For that I need to show LHS of a particular rule. How can we do that in drools6.5. I am using it in jbpm6.5. Please help.

```
import java.lang.Number;

rule "parent"
    @author(rupesh)
    dialect "mvel"
    ruleflow-group "grp"
    when
        obj : Player( totalWinnings >= 10.0 )
    then
        System.out.println(drools.getRule().getMetaData());
        System.out.println(drools.getRule().getMetaAttributes());
        System.out.println(drools.getRule());
end
```

I am not able to get LHS in sysout.

Comment: There is no good way to access the rule's text. You can dig into the implementation and you may find some structure representing the LHS but this isn't in the stable API.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to see the LHS values when a rule is not activated to understand why it happened.

To do that, create a function like this:

```
function boolean debug(double x) {
    System.out.println("lhs_debug(): "+x);
    return true;
}
```

and then modify the rule to use it, like this:

```
rule "parent"
    when
        obj : Player( debug(totalWinnings), totalWinnings >= 10.0 )
    then
        System.out.println("activated: "+obj.totalWinnings);
        //do something
end
```

This will show you all attempts to activate the rule and will help you debug when it was not activated.

Please note that it will be very verbose and time consuming, so it should be removed after debugging.